# apt-cacher-ng | How to re-direct clients when the cacher server is unavailable?

Tags: apt

How can I configure the apt-cacher-ng clients so that when the cacher server is not available, clients can go fetch the packages from the internet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all the research I found out the only way out is proxy + cacher (Eg: squid + apt-cacher-ng)

Comment: Can you tell us what you have found? Other users will benefit from it and possibly improve it.

Answer (score 0):

The `/etc/network/if-up.d` hook found here may be appropriate for some uses cases: https://askubuntu.com/questions/3503/best-way-to-cache-apt-downloads-on-a-lan#answer-25945